# Postgres: find date in between including the date itself

Tags: php, postgresql, date

I have a Posgres table with dateandtime column (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format).

I need to find the rows between a certain date, including the date itself.

I'm currently using this:

```
SELECT x,y,z FROM table WHERE dateandtime between
DATE('".date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($from))."') and
DATE('".date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($to))."')
```

but this shows only the date in between, so that if I select:

from 15/02/2015 - to 15/02/2015. I don't see anything, instead of seeing the day 15th.

Same thing if I do this:

from 14/02/2015 - to 15/02/2015. 
I don't see the 15th but only the 14th.

So my workaround was to check in PHP if the `from` and `to` date are the same, then find that day only. But this is not a good solution and I still have the second part of the problem.

**EDIT as requested**

This is the generated query:

```
SELECT x,y,z FROM table WHERE dateandtime between
DATE('2015-01-15 00:00:00') and
DATE('2015-01-15 00:00:00')
```

So I added an if:

```
SELECT x,y,z FROM table WHERE dateandtime BETWEEN
'".date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($from.' 00:00:00'))."' AND
'".date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($from.' 23:59:59'))."'
```

And this is the result:

```
SELECT x,y,z FROM table WHERE dateandtime BETWEEN
'2015-01-15 00:00:00' AND
'2015-01-15 23:59:59'
```

I have the same problem because the if checks only if the `from` and `to` are the same. If they are not I still have one day outside the scope.

**Added sqlfiddle**

As you can see the 5th of jannuary is not taken: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d50bd/1

Comment: I'll just give you the usual advise on sql injections, please use prepared statements.

Comment: provide us your table with some example data op www.sqlfiddle.com and post the link back here

Comment: Can you also echo and post the generated query?

Comment: @RaymondNijland I did. Check it out pls.

Comment: and the sqlfiddle example?

Comment: Ok, see my edit: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d50bd/1

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution to your problem is using the `<=` and `>=` operators

```
SELECT x,y,z 
FROM table 
WHERE DATE('".date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($from))."') <= dateandtime 
  AND dateandtime <= DATE('".date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($to))."')
```

Comment: Will not work `a BETWEEN x AND y` is equivalent to `a >= x AND a <= y`

Comment: @RaymondNijland You're correct, I confused the order of operators. Seems like `BETWEEN` is less error prone.