# Operator 'Between' doesn't work with date in my Postgres' queries

Tags: php, postgresql, date, between

I assume this question has been posted many times but none of the solutions I found worked for me. However I'm pretty sure that's something basic.

For my website I need to search datas depending on their 'date' 's column.
So I made my query like this: `'SELECT * FROM table WHERE date " BETWEEN " .$dated. " and" .$datef;`

The query seems to be ok, but when I try it I have an error message:

> Operator does not exists: date >= integer ... HINT:  No operator
>   matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add
>   explicit type casts.

I don't undestand why it tries to check if date>=integer.
I verified with an `echo (gettype($dated))` but my variables are string and not integer.

So I tried to cast them into php date using str_to_time and then date() but nothing changed. My variable is still of type string and still considered as an integer when my query is executed.

I found and tried that code in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32347672/postgres-find-date-in-between-including-the-date-itself)

but it said that the function strtotime doesn't exist or maybe it the argument doesn't match. Of course strtotime(integer) can't work...

So if you know why my variable is considered as an integer. 
The user as to type it in an date's input and the values are obtained using `$dated=$_POST['dated']`, the content of my variable is ok, I made my tests with '2014-06-20','2014-06-22' and '06/20/2014', '06/22/2014' but it does not change anything.

If you have any ideas? I feel that this is something very stupid but I can't find where is mistake...

Thank you!

Comment: Provide the full SQL please along with the variable substitution, copy & pasted, not typed in by hand.  $dated or $datef might be wrong, and as-is, your SQL is incorrect (no space after the "and").

Comment: You should **not** inline query parameters as it will make your application vulnerable to SQL injection. Use `pg_send_query_params` or use a prepared statement to do that. Then you will find out parameters can be cast `SELECT … WHERE column >= $1::timetstamptz`

Comment: I'm sorry I just begin in php and pgsql, your solution seems to be good greg, the date is not interpeted as 2014-06-20 but as 1988, an integer.
I look for the pg_send_query_params and it seems to solve my issue, but I have another problem:
I can't use parameters to replace a column or a table name, when I try it I have the following error:  syntax error near $1.
Do you know if there's a good way to use variable for table name or columns? I also tried execute() as it was suggested in a forum but it doesn't seem to work either.
If it can help I will copy & paste my code tomorrow.
Thank you!